# External Storage issue

Tags: acumatica

we have enabled external file storage and using Local File Storage as Provider, we are successfully able to move files to storage but when moving back from storage to database we are getting an exception like the file is not found: C:\FileStorage\c795f1fb-46fd-444b-898f-825f87d19fb5.bin, can someone help me out on this, how can i find the file and solve this issue.

Comment: Was a backup/restore operation involved just before the issue happened?

Comment: What about the content of 'c:\FileStorage' folder on the machine where Acumatica is installed? If you have access to that machine, does the directory exists and what does it contains?

Comment: Hello, yes I have restored snapshot prior to this and I could not able to find file in that folder in server machine

Comment: The primary cause for this error is taking a partial snapshot and restoring it. Doing so will not backup/restore the files. I don't think snapshot will copy those files.

Comment: We have taken a full snapshot, is their any way we can find what file is missing from db queries etc.,

Comment: File storage has been offset to external storage local folder. I'm pretty sure snapshot takes file from the database, not from external storage. So before taking the snapshot you would have to go to the External File Storage screen and move files to database. At the time you took the snapshot files that were only on local folder (not in database) were ignored. The snapshot doesn't contain those files and you can't query the db about missing files on hard drive either. You need to locally check the folder on the target machine. The fix would be to manually copy those missing files.